# What is the proof of this property of integrals involving $e?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, proof-explanation

I was reading my calculus book wherein I came across a note, being worth of attention. It says:

> Integrals in the form of $\int P(x)e^{ax}dx$ have a special property. After calculating the integral, we obtain a function in the form of $Q(x)e^{ax}$ where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial of the same degree as of $P(x)$. This is called method of indefinite coefficients.

Like for example, we do $\displaystyle\int (3x^3-17)e^{2x}dx$, We can do it traditionally by integration by parts but let me show you my or rather author's method :

Let this be equal to $(Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D)e^{2x}$

Now differentiating both sides we get, $$(3x^3-17)e^{2x}=2(Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D)e^{2x}+e^{2x}(3Ax^2+2Bx+C)$$
Now we will cancel $e^{2x}$ on both sides and the rest is equating the coefficients.

I have seen that this property is applicable in every question but I don't know the mathematical proof of this. It wasn't even in the book.

Any help regarding the proof is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Induction on deg $P$ and integration by parts.

Comment: Note that $d(Qe^{a x})/dx = [a Q(x) +Q'(x)]e^{ax}$. $[a Q(x) +Q'(x)]$ is clearly a polynomial. Can its degree be different from that of $Q(x)$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Exactly

Comment: @eyeballfrog This does not imply that $Pe^{ax}$ has an antiderivative of the form $Qe^{ax} + C$. It is not immediate that every polynomial $P$ of degree $n$ can be expressed in the form $aQ+Q'$ for some polynomial $Q$ of degree $n$ and any $a \in \mathbb{R}$. The argument would also require uniqueness of the antiderivative up to a constant, although that is simple to prove.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

> $\int P(x) e^{ax}\, \mathrm{d}x = Q(x) e^{ax}$ with $\deg(P(x)) = \deg(Q(x)) $

is equivalent (by the definition of antiderivative) to showing that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}Q(x) e^{ax} = P(x) e^{ax}
$$
where $\deg(P(x)) = \deg(Q(x)) $.

Thus, writing $Q(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\color{blue}{n} c_k x^k$ for some constants $c_k$ with $c_n \neq 0$ then $\deg(Q(x)) = \color{blue}{n}$. So we get

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}Q(x) e^{ax}  & =\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left( c_0 e^{ax} +\sum_{k=1}^n c_k x^ke^{ax}\right)\\
& =ac_0e^{ax} +\sum_{k=1}^n c_k \left( kx^{k-1} e^{ax} + x^kae^{ax}\right)\\
& \overset{\color{purple}{k-1\to k}}{=} \left(ac_0+ \sum_{k=\color{purple}{0}}^{\color{purple}{n-1}} c_{k+1} (k+1) x^{k} +\sum_{k=1}^n c_k ax^k\right) e^{ax}\\
& = \underbrace{\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}C_k x^k\right)}_{P(x)} e^{ax}
\end{align}
where
$$
C_k =\begin{cases}
a c_0 + c_1, & k=0\\
c_{k+1}(k+1) + c_ka, & 1\le k \le n-1\\
c_ka, & k=n 
\end{cases}
$$
and since $C_n = c_n a \neq 0$ then $\deg(P(x)) = n$ as well.

Comment: What you have demonstrated is *not* equivalent to the statement; it is also necessary to at least remark that the $c_k$ can be expressed as linear combinations of the $C_k$, though this is simple with the work you have done. This also only holds since the antiderivative is unique up to a constant (note the statement is also missing a constant so it is not entirely correct).

Answer (score 1):

The best method for this question is to use induction and integration by parts (as suggested by W. Fan), as well as the linearity of the integral. Note that if $P(x) = c_n x^n + \cdots + c_0$,

$$\int P(x) e^{ax} dx = \int (c_n x^n + \cdots + c_0) e^{ax} dx $$

$$= \sum_{i=0}^n c_k\int x^ke^{ax}dx$$

Thus, it suffices to show that the result holds for $x^k$. We do this by induction on $k$. The basis for $k=0$ is simple to verify. Now consider, for $k$ in general, the integral:

$$\int x^k e^{ax} dx$$

$$\frac{1}{a}x^ke^{ax} -\frac{k}{a}\int x^{k-1}e^{ax} dx$$

for $a \neq 0$. This latter integral is $e^{ax}$ multiplied by a polynomial of degree $(k-1)$ by the induction hypothesis, so it follows that $\int x^k e^{ax} dx$ is $e^{ax}$ multiplied by a polynomial of degree $k$. $\square$

**Remark**: note that the statement is not true for $a \neq 0$ (by direct verification). The statement is also missing the clause that $Q(x)e^{ax}$ is the antiderivative up to a constant, which is apparent when verifying the basis.

This argument also gives $Q$ explicitly with a little bit more effort. As an exercise, show that:

$$Q(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n  c_k \bigg(\frac{1}{a}x^k-\frac{k}{a^2}x^{k-1}+\frac{k(k-1)}{a^3}x^{k-2}+\cdots +{(-1)}^k\frac{k!}{a^{k+1}} \bigg)$$

where $P(x) = c_n x^n + \cdots + c_0$ as before.

Answer (score 1):

The problem reduces to finding the polynomial $Q$ of degree $n = \deg P$ such that $P = aQ + Q'$.

Differentiating $n$ times and eliminating $Q', Q'', \dots, Q^{(n)}$ between the equations gives:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
P &= aQ + \color{red}{\bcancel{Q'}}
\\ P' &= \color{red}{\bcancel{aQ'}} + \color{blue}{\bcancel{Q''}} \quad &&\big|\;\cdot \color{red}{\frac{-1}{a}}
\\ P'' &= \color{blue}{\bcancel{aQ''}} + \bcancel{Q'''} \quad &&\big|\;\cdot \color{blue}{\frac{+1}{a^2}}
\\ \dots
\\ P^{(n)} &= \bcancel{aQ^{(n)}} + \xcancel{Q^{(n+1)}} \quad &&\big|\;\cdot \frac{(-1)^n}{a^n}
\\ \hline
P - \frac{1}{a} P' + \frac{1}{a^2} P'' - \dots + (-1)^n \frac{1}{a^{n}} P^{(n)} &= aQ
\end{align}
$$
$$
\iff\quad Q = \frac{1}{a} P - \frac{1}{a^2} P' + \frac{1}{a^3} P'' - \dots + (-1)^n \frac{1}{a^{n+1}} P^{(n)}
$$

Comment: Just mentioning that formally this can be derived from the geometric series: $(aI+D)^{-1} = a^{-1}I - a^{-2}D+a^{-3}D^2-+ \cdots$.

Comment: @MartinR That is good insight, indeed. The telescoping shown above is just an ad-hoc proof of that in the case of a finite sum (with $D^k\,P \equiv 0$ for $k \gt n$).